# Continuar con peticion ajax, despues de validaciones en php

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

¿Cómo podría construir un formulario que tras recoger los datos del formulario, los mande mediante una petición AJAX a un archivo PHP y este a su vez los valide en la BD, regrese una respuesta y dicha respuesta se mande a un mensaje HTML con botones de validación y tras la elección de uno de estos botones continué o no con la petición misma petición AJAX?

Un ejemplo:

Supongamos que tengo un formulario de registro de clientes, al momento de mandar mi petición AJAX para registrar al cliente, primero PHP hace la validación en la BD para verificar si el nombre existe, tras hacerla, me muestra que ya hay una persona registrada con el mismo nombre, entonces me sale un mensaje en el FRONT comentándome que hay un nombre igual en mi base de datos y me pregunta si deseo continuar con el registro (duplicar el nombre), si yo le doy confirmar, entonces se continua con el registro.

Mi duda es si esto es posible con la misma petición AJAX, o tendría que construir otra.

Comment: Se me ocurre que en el callback de tu ajax construyas el botón de confirmación de duplicar nombre y le agregues un evento ahí mismo, donde al darle click hagas otra petición ajax, donde te permita hacer la inserción sin validar el nombre duplicado

Comment: cada consulta es una petición...